# Hook for gems to add middleware on the Rack stack with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I am trying to find out how a gem in the Rails 3 gemfile can automatically add middleware to the Rack stack. I am looking for the hook in that gem.
For example ... when I add the devise gem to my Rails 3 gemfile, then devise somehow adds warden as middleware on the Rack stack. This seems to work automatically. There is no further configuration needed in the Rails 3 app. I guess there is automatically called a special class/method from boot.rb. Any hints how this process really works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't exactly show how a gem/plugin hooks into middleware, but this is how you can do it. Based on that, a gem/plugin can do the same things:

To insert middleware, you can run this in an initialize file.

```
ActionController::Dispatcher.middleware.insert_before(ActionController::Base.session_store, FlashSessionCookieMiddleware, ActionController::Base.session_options[:key])
```

The above will insert a Flash Cookie Middleware (custom code) before the session_store rack is loaded.

To see your own middleware, run **rake middleware**

```
use Rack::Lock
use ActionController::Failsafe
use FlashSessionCookieMiddleware, "_xxxxxx_session"
use ActionController::Session::CookieStore, #<Proc:0x00000001037d4f20@(eval):8>
use ActionController::ParamsParser
use Rack::MethodOverride
use Rack::Head
use ActionController::StringCoercion
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
```

Comment: That explains the part of how to add middleware to the Rack stack, thanks. But I still wonder what method/hook of the gem is called by Rails 3, when the gem is just in the Gemfile?

Comment: Ok, I think I solved it. The problem was that I couldn't find the initialize file you mentioned in a gem. In Rails 2.x it was rails/init.rb. But this isn't called in Rails 3 anymore. The way to go is to create a lib/gem_name.rb (where gem_name is the name of that gem). That will be called automatically by Rails 3 when the gem is specified in the Gemfile. And there you can add the middleware. (see https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3745-railsinitrb-is-not-being-called-anymore)

Comment: Cool about the Gems! For Rails 2.3 and above (after they moved to rack) -- you create a file named whatever.rb in the directory config/initializers

Answer (score 10):

You should use a Railtie. In fact, this is the very example given in the [Rails::Railtie documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html).

```
class MyRailtie < Rails::Railtie
  initializer "my_railtie.configure_rails_initialization" do |app|
    app.middleware.use MyRailtie::Middleware
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the cleanest answer, and I would add that and Engine is a Railtie so you can use that initializer method in your engine, you're not forced to make a separate railtie

Answer (score 8):

To insert middleware in a gem, you should add it to the gem's engine.

in `lib/gem_name/engine.rb`

```
require 'rails'

module GemName
  class Engine < Rails::Engine

    config.app_middleware.insert_before(Warden::Manager, Rack::OpenID)

  end
end
```

Comment: That's it. `config.app_middleware` instead of `config.middleware` is important.

Comment: +1000% on this.  From a `Railtie`, use `app.config.app_middleware.insert_before` in order to have your middleware configured _after_ the default is setup.